# how to use while condition when enter -1 then entries will stop in java

Tags: java, while-loop

how we enter -1 through while loop to stop the loop entries but my code is not working i want to enter entries according to my need then hit enter -1 to stop or come back to the while loop .kindly give the solution

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("enter number");
int i = 0;        
i = input.nextInt();
while(i < 0){
System.out.println("hello entries");
 if(i == -1)
 break;
 i++;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Usually you have count of entries followed by exactly that number of entries OR you have entries with a sentinel value. Why do you want to have both? What do you want to happen if they don't agree?

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);
    int i ;
while((i = input.nextInt() ) != -1){
    System.out.println("hello entries" + i);
}
```

Comment: Whar error are you getting ? Try now I have edited the post.

Comment: bro its okay now tell me one thing more how i get the strings in input values ?

Comment: i got the answer but it comes 2 time if i enter 1 then next 1 is coming in output

Comment: For string you need to change the nextInt() method to next() and the type of i from int to String.    String i = "" ;
while(!(i = input.next()).equals("-1")){
    System.out.println("hello entries" + i);
}

Comment: The first time you got 1 because you entered 1 as input and next time because that 1 was the output  as well

Comment: thanks bro i got it lot of thanks bro :) after removing System.out.println("hello entries" + i);

Comment: Mention not !! If you find my inputs helpful just acknowledge by upvoting my answer

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like you have a few issues here. First, you are wanting to exit while i != -1 as I understand it. Also, you increment i with each loop of the while loop. This is causing your conditional i < 0 to be false. I think what you are looking for is similar to the other answer. You want to have a variable that acts as your input and also control.

```
int entry = 0;
while(entry != 1){
      i = input.nextInt();
      Do Something with the entry
}
```